# Sound doesn't play for embedded flash movie

Tags: javascript, flash, audio, swfobject

Good day.

I have script:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="580" height="370" id="AnimationObject">
        <param name="movie" value="./Flash/1384290997.swf">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="loop" value="false">
        <param name="play" value="true">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
        <param name="movie" value="./Sounds/SuccessSounds/1384290997.wav">

        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="./Flash/1384290997.swf" width="580" height="370" id="ItemEditAnimationObject">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="loop" value="false">
        <param name="play" value="true">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
        <param name="movie" value="./Sounds/SuccessSounds/1384290997.wav">

        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->

      </object>
```

For start animation with sound i use

```
swfobject.getObjectById('AnimationObject').Play();
```

*Animation play, but sound dont play.*

*Tell me please where error?*

*Why sound dont play and how play him ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sound will be not play in your code.

also you need change `<param name="movie" value="./Sounds/SuccessSounds/1384290997.wav">` on `<param name="movie" value="./Flash/1384290997.swf">`

Comment: i edit post, i think Q see that his post edited and past link or skip edit

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because you're having the same `name="movie"` for the .swf and the .wav files,
Change that and it should work.